# How to Encrypt a string in PHP, and decrypt it in Visual basic 6?

Tags: php, encryption

I have an application in VB which communicates over HTTP with the WEB app built with PHP.

The PHP application will send an encrypted value(string) to the VB app, the VB app should be able to decrypt it to get the string.

FYI: *I am using VB6 and PHP 5.3 with Xampp.*

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The programming language/platform is irrelevant - what will matter is that you implement the same encryption/decryption algorithm at both ends.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to encrypt data ?
Depending on the answer :

- you should use https
- or use mcrypt php extension
- or create your own method

Comment: I suspect that while he has control over the receiving VB6 app, he doesn't have control over the PHP webservice, so has to deal with what he's given....

Comment: I used the Xor ( ^ operator) functionality using an unique KEY (numeric) on both the application and it works great.

Answer (score 0):

Check [Encryption for C++, Visual Basic, php using PC1](http://www.expertcore.org/viewtopic.php?f=49&t=1816). Someone has reported it works perfectly with php and VB6.